# Quickest/best way to read XML

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read potentially large (~300mb) XML files, and edit some of the nodes. Basically I need to:

- Read the XML from the start
- Whenever I find a node called trgt
- Add some text to it

What's the best way to approach this in C#? Which XML classes should I use to find and edit the nodes I need to change?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VTD-XML is the only XML parsing lib that supports a feature called incremental update. It is also memory efficient and performant. But it requires you to download it as a third party lib.

Comment: Impressive - this is definetely something I'll be looking at. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you state that this is your own product in your answers, lest they be taken as spam.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience of transforming some very large (2GB+) xml files (don't ask!) I found xsl transforms to be the quickest - The engines involved are heavily optimised for such tasks, compare to any manual looping etc you might try.

Comment: You know I think you're right. Although XSLT can be intimidating to some people.

Comment: Fair comment, although most transforms are relatively simple, and you can always post a question on SO!

Comment: which xsl engine is it that is so optimized?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`Linq-to-XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  in short, read with [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), parse and add data with `Linq`.  This will not be the fastest code, but will probably be the quickest to write.

If you have memory constraints, you will probably have to parse it manually (i.e. load only part of it in memory, process that part, replace it in the file)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a fairly simple operation similar to find-and-replace, you could try treating it as a normal text file instead of an xml document. I imagine that might be faster than all the xml parsing.